# How can I combine my guitar playing, compositions in Sibelius and an music maker software together

Tags: electric-guitar, recording, production, sibelius

To begin I feel I have to mention that, while I did get information regarding recording and composition, I feel as if they did not answer my case entirely.
So here goes:

I have been playing classical guitar for years and have numerous compositions stored on Sibelius that I would like to make more 'realistic' and 'listenable' as the music on Sibelius sounds unnatural. I know that I can plug my guitar directly into my PC (do I really need a preamp?) I don't know, however, how to convert my compositions for other instruments that I cant play, into actual instrument sounds as the Sibelius instruments sound extremely fake.

I understand that music maker software like MAGIX Music Maker exist, but does that mean I HAVE to buy a MIDI controller or can I import my Sibelius compositions to the music maker software?

Answer (score 1):

First - yes, if you want to play your guitar directly into your PC you really do want an audio interface with a preamp. You will not be able to get good sound quality otherwise.

Second - Sibelius can sound amazing. Various film scores have been created using it (including Avatar) so you may need to look deeper into it.

As Bernard pointed out, you can export to MIDI, which MAGIX Music Maker should be able to use, but I don't think that's going to give you better MIDI samples than Sibelius. Worth a try though.

I'm not 100% certain why you want to export from Sibelius to Music Maker - Sibelius should be far superior. And if you are recording your guitar, can you explain why it doesn't sound realistic?

Maybe I'm not understanding your question well enough.

Comment: Also, different VSTs can be used with Sibelius, as well. The sound clip on the splash screen of older version of Sibelius was all scored and exported audio from Sibelius itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is File > Export > MIDI what you're looking for? I don't have a copy of MAGIX Music Maker to hand, but you should then be able to import the file into the programme fairly easily.